# Removing the bottom error caps only on matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I wanted to display only half error bars, as they are symetric ; as I had no clue how to do this with a "clean way", I chose to use asymetric errors with 0 on the bottom side ; but then, when I displayed caps, I realised this was not the best way to do this.

Here's the code :

```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  N = 5
  men_means = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
  men_std = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)

  ind = np.arange(N)
  width = 0.35

  fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  rects1 = ax.bar(ind, men_means, width, color='r',yerr=[np.zeros(len(men_std)),men_std],capsize = 5)

  women_means = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
  women_std = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
  rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, women_means, width, color='y',yerr=[np.zeros(len(women_std)),women_std],capsize = 5)

  plt.show()
```

And this is the plot I get :[image: myPlot]. As you can see, my way of plotting half error bars is probably not what should be done.

So is there any way to hide the bottom cap line or a better way to plot half error bars ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`ax.errorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar) has the option to set `uplims=True` or `lolims=True` to signify that the means repesent the upper or lower limits, respectively. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like you can use these options directly with `ax.bar`, so we have to plot the errorbar and the bar plot separately.

The documentation for the `uplims/lolims` options in `ax.errorbar`:

> `lolims` / `uplims` / `xlolims` / `xuplims` : bool, optional, default:None
>
> These arguments can be used to indicate that a value gives only upper/lower limits. In that case a caret symbol is used to indicate this. lims-arguments may be of the same type as `xerr` and `yerr`. To use limits with inverted axes, `set_xlim()` or `set_ylim()` must be called before errorbar().

Note that using this option changes your caps to arrows. See below for an example of how to change them back to caps, if you need flat caps instead of arrows.

You can see these options in action in [this example on the matplotlib website](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/errorbar_limits.html).

Now, here's your example, modified:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
men_means = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
men_std = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)

ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.35

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, men_means, width, color='r')
err1 = ax.errorbar(ind, men_means, yerr=men_std, lolims=True, capsize = 0, ls='None', color='k')

women_means = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
women_std = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, women_means, width, color='y')
err2 = ax.errorbar(ind + width, women_means, yerr=women_std, lolims=True, capsize = 0, ls='None', color='k')

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you don't like the arrows, you change them to flat caps, by changing the marker of the `caplines` that are returned (as the second item) from `ax.errorbar`. We can change them from the arrows to the marker style `_`, and then control their size with `.set_markersize`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
men_means = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
men_std = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)

ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.35

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, men_means, width, color='r')
plotline1, caplines1, barlinecols1 = ax.errorbar(
        ind, men_means, yerr=men_std, lolims=True,
        capsize = 0, ls='None', color='k')

caplines1[0].set_marker('_')
caplines1[0].set_markersize(20)

women_means = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
women_std = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, women_means, width, color='y')
plotline2, caplines2, barlinecols2 = ax.errorbar(
        ind + width, women_means, yerr=women_std,
        lolims=True, capsize = 0, ls='None', color='k')

caplines2[0].set_marker('_')
caplines2[0].set_markersize(10)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You mentionned that you didn't know if there was a simple way to avoid changing the caps to arrows. So does that mean there is a way, although not an easy one ?

Comment: Actually, just looked at that, and its not too difficult. See my edit

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution is to use zorder. The grid has `zorder=0`. Setting the errorbar to `zorder=1` and the bar to `zorder=2`and lowering the bottom error a bit will hide the lower error bar with little effort.  This also allows to use `bar_label`. The only downside is if `alpha` is used for the bars.

I also changed to use `np.zeros_like(std)` instead of `np.zeros(len(std))` and use `error_kw` to style the errorbar.

```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  N = 5


  ind = np.arange(N)
  width = 0.8

  fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  
  women_means = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
  women_std = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
  rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, women_means, width, color='y',yerr=[np.zeros_like(women_std)+0.5,women_std],zorder=2,error_kw=dict(capsize = 10, capthick=1,zorder=1))
  
  ax.bar_label(rects2,labels=[f'{v:.2f} ± {e:.2f}' for v,e in zip(women_means, women_std)], padding=10, fontsize=14, label_type='edge')

  fig.tight_layout()
  plt.show()
```

[image: Zorder and barlabel example]

Comment: though what I did notice is, that the black Tip is still a bit visible behind the bar. To remove this just don"t use np.zeroes but something bigger than zeroes for the bottom errorbars

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks,
based on your answer, method below is my solution:

```
def process_error_bar(ax, x, y, y_err, marker_size):
    """
    hide half error_bar
    :param ax: plt.subplots()
    :param x: x position
    :param y: y position
    :param y_err: y errors
    :param marker_size: size
    """

    lolims = []
    uplims = []
    for y_value in y:
        if y_value < 0:
            lolims.append(False)
            uplims.append(True)
        else:
            lolims.append(True)
            uplims.append(False)

    plotline, caplines, barlinecols = ax.errorbar(
        x, y, yerr=y_err, lolims=lolims, uplims=uplims,
        capsize=0, ls='None', color='k')

    # [arrow] -> [-]
    for capline in caplines:
        capline.set_marker('_')
        capline.set_markersize(marker_size)
```

[image]